# common layout for paid and free flavours, with ad in free

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have a main activity with a layout that I would like to re-use for a paid and free flovours. I have an xml file with an AdView in it. How do I use the AdView in just the free verion.

Comment: You may refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522373/6238866

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate resources for each flavours with same name.

[image]
For Further reference you can check this link
https://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/